# Symfony2 - base64_decode in twig

Tags: php, symfony, service, base64, twig

I need to display a picture in my twig template. I get this picture in my controller as string encoded in base64, so I created a personal function in my service to decode the base64 :

```
public function base64ToImg($base64)
{
    $img_str = 'image/png;base64,'.$base64;
    $img_data = explode(";",$img_str);
    $type_img = $img_data[0];
    $final_img = explode(",",$img_data[1]);
    header("Content-type:".$type_img);

    return base64_decode($final_img[1]);
}
```

and in my controller :

```
$logo = $this->container->get('services.utils')->base64ToImg($mydata);
echo $logo;
die();
```

It works, but when i send `$logo` to my template with a `render`, the picture isn't displayed with `{{ logo }}`. I tried to create my own twig function too but doesn't works also...

There is a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: You are doing wrong things. Why do you need `$img_str` here? Your `$type_img` is always `image/png`, your `$final_img[1]` is always equals to `$base64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you trying to display the image inside the template? If you use the base64encoded string you'd probably need `data:image/png;base64,encoded string` in your image tag.

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Other options are saving to file or using a script to display the image

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="/controller/image?id=foo" />
```